Chrome for MacOS is handling CSS filter brightness and hue-rotate properties differently
Small bit of background: I store my images and icons in a pure red colouring then allow administrators of the site to adjust the hue-rotation and brightness allowing them to control colour schemes / theming.
The issue I am facing is that in Mac OS Chrome, the output from a CSS filter property is rendering drastically differently.
The code is:


div {
  background: #ff0000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  filter: hue-rotate(30deg) brightness(3.2);
  float: left;
}
div + div {
  background: #ff5200;
  -webkit-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
<div></div>
<div></div>



Both div elements should be the same colour, and on every browser apart from Mac OS Chrome they are, but in Mac OS Chrome, the filtered div is instead #ffe400.
Replicated across several of our team who use Mac OS but I run Windows so can't test directly and annoyingly when tested in BrowserStack the issue isn't present...


Can confirm I see the same thing. If only the hue-rotate filter is applied, the colours seem to match, but one is darker than the other. Then the brightness filter takes it to a different colour altogether. Seems weird it would be different between WIndows and Mac, and also between Chrome and Safari on Mac.

This doesn't explain the browser differences, but according to here and here the results are not great in general.

Reasons for Differences:
Rendering Engine: Chrome's Blink engine may handle filters differently on macOS.
Color Management: macOS color profiles (e.g., P3 gamut) can affect brightness and hue.
Hardware Acceleration: GPU rendering can introduce variations.
Solutions:
Test filters across platforms (use tools like BrowserStack).
Use @supports (-webkit-appearance: none) for macOS-specific tweaks:
@supports (-webkit-appearance: none) {
.example {
    filter: brightness(1.1) hue-rotate(15deg);
}

}
Debug with Chrome DevTools.
Use SVG filters for more consistent results.

I'd understand that it could be a colour profile thing if it was a minor difference but a completely different colour seems strange.
As mentioned in the question, Browserstack doesnt show the issue, only on a physical machine is it present.
Also the CSS supports property wouldn't change anything as it is adjusting the colour (so must be supported) just how its handling it is different.
